# Which freeware analysis software most closely resembles the functionality of Matlab DSP toolbox

Tags: dsp

I'm looking for some freeware that will do (as much as possible) of what Matlab does DSP-wise...

- Filtering tools
- Modulation
- File I/O (as I need these to compare vhdl simulation results to software computed results)

I've used both Scilab and Octave.  I'm wondering which one (or another unmentioned option) would be the best freeware DSP design replacement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try SciPy/NumPy and Matplotlib if you're into Python.  It doesn't have all of the functionality of the Matlab toolboxes but lots of the basic functionality.

I actually doubt you'll find a complete freeware replacement for the DSP toolbox.   The toolboxes are the hard part and where Mathworks puts most of its effort.  The general functionality is easier to find for free.

Comment: If you want an easy way into NumPy/SciPy, give Spyder a shot, or the enthought package.  The enthought package isn't free, but you can get access with an educational e-mail address.

Comment: In school, we used Matlab for everything, but on my own time, I use NumPy/SciPy for everything.  There's also the confusingly-named http://www.pythonxy.com/ project, which is based on(?) Spyder.

Comment: The ipython shell is very useful.  It is a good companion for Numpy/Scipy.

Answer (score 4):

There's also:

[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)

and

[Rlab](http://rlab.sourceforge.net/)

which may have some of the functionality you're looking for.

The site [dspGuru](http://www.dspguru.com/) may have other useful suggestions for you too.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Sci-lab which has a simulink modeling type thing built in.